# Can't connect to MySQL via PHP "Name or service not known"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website, which sends input data with AJAX via a PHP script to a MySQL database.

The JavaScript/AJAX part is working but the PHP script doesn't get executed, and if I paste the URL from the PHP script into my browser I get:

> Connection failed:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name
> or service not known

The host, server, password and database are 100% correct.

My PHP code is

```
<?php

$host = '';
$user = '';
$pswd = '';
$database = '';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pswd, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die ("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connection successful";

$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Names(s) VALUES(?)";


if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {

$sql->bind_param('s', $name);

  $stmt = mysqli_parse($conn, $sql);
  $stmt->execute();

  echo "Created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Any code? How do you connect?

Comment: Without any code hard to tell. Either way, make sure the hostname for your DB connection does not have `http://` in it. It also could be a DNS issue.

Comment: it doesn't. Also there are other files in the same folder in the File Manager from my Provider that are reachable and power the website. @GuidoFaecke

Comment: Mysql service isn't running...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854947/5947043

Comment: @ADyson but I excluded both of the possible issues ***A***. the hostname is wrong: I copied and pasted the name which I got from my DB Provider ***B*** other files from the same folder are available, so it would mean that there is not DNS problem, right?

Comment: @KenLee as said in the comment above in ***A*** I got the $host, $username and $database _directly_ from the dedicated mysql server provider and pasted it.

Comment: As I mentioned, when I paste the url from the location of the php script I get "failed:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" so is the issue related to the url which is used to send the data to the php script rather than $host

Comment: `other files from the same folder are available, so it would mean that there is not DNS problem`...it depends what those files do. Do they successfully access the database using the same details that you're trying in this code? If there's a DNS problem, it would be because the PHP code cannot look up the address of the DB server, which isn't related to whether other files on that webserver are accessible.

Comment: `so is the issue related to the url which is used to send the data to the php script rather than $host`...no, the problem is that the PHP code is unable to reach the host address specified in your mysql connection.

Comment: @ADyson the other files are .html files and thus don't access the DB. But $host is 100% correct, so I don't know how I could proceed

Comment: `host is 100% correct`...well the computer disagrees with you. Either it isn't 100% correct, or there's some sort of network issue which is preventing the machine hosting the PHP code from either contacting a DNS server, or contacting the target host. Is this PHP code running in a hosted server, or on your own personal machine, or what? And where is the database hosted?

Comment: @ADyson The PHP is located at Bluehost and the DB at IONOS, as a managed server.

Comment: Maybe there is some firewall between them then? Either outbound on the bluehost and/or inbound on the IONOS side. Or maybe bluehost has DNS issues, or the DNS that the bluehost machine uses doesn't know about the IONOS host. Have you run this PHP code from another machine to see if you get a different outcome?

Comment: @ADyson I tried some things and also contacted my providers. I set up a DB in Bluehost, where my PHP Files are stored as well, so there shouldn't be a problem in general. Nevertheless I now get the error "Connection refused" in the mysqli_connect() line

Comment: You mean when you try to connect to the Bluehost db? Is there not any more detail than that?

Comment: Yes, when I try to connect to Bluehost DB, DB and PHP files are hosted there now.

Comment: Does the error message not contain any more information than that? The usual reason for that error is if you specify the wrong port or, again, if there's a firewall blocking the connection

Comment: @ADyson connection is now successful but the data is still not inserted into the DB. No Error

Comment: Are you sure? mysqli_parse is not a real function as far as I can see, unless you've defined that yourself in your own code somewhere?

Comment: And of course if you're still testing this by putting the URL into your browser then it won't receive any $_POST variable

Comment: Also if you're not seeing errors it might be because they're simply not enabled? See https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting for how to enable general PHP error reporting. Then add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `new mysqli()` command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically as well.

Answer (score -1):

Besides the initial issue. You have it a bit jumbled up. The `bind_param` is off.

```php
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
```

But, since you don't make it past `die()`, there is something wrong with either of `$host, $user, $pswd, $database` or maybe a firewall or DNS issue somewhere. Or the server might not be running as mentioned in the comments.